# Replace string in files with certain file extension

Tags: ubuntu

I want to replace `mysql_real_escape_string` with `mysqli_real_escape_string` in all php files on ubuntu desktop.... how do I do that?

@note - If this is a duplicate, then the "related questions" needs to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name *.php -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i 's/mysql_real_escape_string/mysqli_real_escape_string/g'
```

Comment: I fixed some typos in your command line (no argument to -type, and you were using -0 on xargs without -print0 on find).

Comment: Left the "g" off of the last `escape_strin` but that's perfect, thanks